# Scrapy: How to send data to the pipeline from a custom filter without downloading

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

To catch all redirection paths, including when the final url was already crawled, I wrote a custom duplicate filter:

```
import logging

from scrapy.dupefilters import RFPDupeFilter
from seoscraper.items import RedirectionItem

class CustomURLFilter(RFPDupeFilter):

    def __init__(self, path=None, debug=False):
        super(CustomURLFilter, self).__init__(path, debug)

    def request_seen(self, request):
        request_seen = super(CustomURLFilter, self).request_seen(request)

        if request_seen is True:
            item = RedirectionItem()
            item['sources'] = [ u for u in request.meta.get('redirect_urls', u'') ]
            item['destination'] = request.url

        return request_seen
```

Now, how can I send the RedirectionItem directly to the pipeline? 
Is there a way to instantiate the pipeline from the custom filter so that I can send data directly? Or shall I also create a custom scheduler and get the pipeline from there but how?

Comment: I don't quite understand your use case, and this is not an answer to sending items from dupefilters, but you could imagine a spider middleware to implement the request filtering, a bit like `OffsiteMiddleware`, and return `RedirectionItem`S from there

Comment: @paultrmbrth The use case is the following: For SEO reasons, I want to trace redirections within a website and the meta 'redirect_urls' is perfect for that. But if example.com/A1, example.com/A2 & example.com/A3 redirect to the same url example.com/A, the dupefilter will only let one of them reach the pipeline => example.com/A3. Using dont_filter is not an option since I really don't want the final url to be crawled multiple times, just capture the redirection paths ... Could I use the same filter within the custom spider middleware?

Comment: So actually, my new question is: How can we grab the dupefilter instance from a custom spider middleware?

Comment: If you instantiate a scrapy item and `yield` it doesn't it go to the pipeline?

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida No, I tried yielding the item that but unfortunately it does not send it to the pipeline, it actually stops the crawl!

Comment: @paultrmbrth So, a possibility could be to create a RedirectionMiddleware, that can access the dupefilter object via crawler.engine.slot.scheduler.df, then 1. in process_spider_output, check request_seen for all requests in result, and 2. When request_seen is True then create a RedirectionItem & yield it to the pipeline. Am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, something like that